# Inserting Before/After Node in Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to insert nodes in a list based on the value of a data member. Basically, if the member `isVip` evaluates to true, that node gets precedence, and should be inserted ahead of any regular node (but behind any existing VIP nodes). Regular nodes simply get added at the end of the list.

I'm pretty sure I have a good idea of how to use two pointers to step through the list and insert elements for n > 2 where n is the number of current list members, but I'm sort of conceptually stuck for the case when there's only one node.

Here is my working version of code below:

```
void SelfStorageList::rentLocker(Locker e) {

int count = 0;
    LockerNode *p = head;

if (isEmpty()) {
    head = new LockerNode(e);
    tail = head;
}

for(;p!=0;count++, p=p->next) {

    if(count == 1) {

        if (e.isVip) {

                        if(p->objLocker.isVip)  {
                           LockerNode*p = new LockerNode(e, p->next);

            }
                    }

           }


}
```

As you can see, I'm checking to see if the passed in object is VIP, and then whether the current one is. Here, I've hit some trouble. Assuming both are VIP, will this line:

```
LockerNode*p = new LockerNode(e, p->next);
```

put the passed in locker object in the correct place (i.e. after the current VIP one). If so, would:

```
LockerNode*p = new LockerNode(e, p);
```

equivalently place it before? Is the use or absence of the 'next' member of the node what defines the placement location, or is it something entirely different?

Hope someone can clear my doubts, and sorry if it seem a foolish question! Thanks!

Comment: You should modify `p->next` somewhere. How does the constructor `LockerNode(e,p)` look?

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass the `Locker` argument *by value*? That means it will be a *copy*. You should think about passing it by reference (or as a pointer).

Comment: Nope, value should be fine. I am OK with copies, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over the list while the *next* node have `isVip` set (`current->next->isVip`). After the iteration, the last node visited will be the last with `isVip` set, and you should insert the new node after that one.

---

It can be implemented in fewer lines, without the explicit `isEmpty` check, and without any counter. Even less than that if you use a standard container instead.